# viewing a tif image file using OpenCV in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, tiff, opencv

I have a thermal image in TIF format which I can see using `display` command in Ubuntu.
I also have the following information from the image file:

```
$ file Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif
Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif: Big TIFF image data, little-endian
$ exiv2 Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif
File name       : Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif
File size       : 2097433 Bytes
MIME type       : 
Image size      : 0 x 0
Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif: No Exif data found in the file
```

also

```
$  tiffinfo Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif
TIFF Directory at offset 0x200010 (2097168)
  Image Width: 1024 Image Length: 1024
  Bits/Sample: 16
  Sample Format: unsigned integer
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Software: ExaminIR
```

When I run the following cell:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-2756e499dadf> in <module>
      1 import cv2
      2 img = cv2.imread("Rec-000026_16bit_counts.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
----> 3 cv2.imshow('image',img)
      4 cv2.waitKey(0)
      5 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 
error: OpenCV(3.4.9) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:382: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: It looks like OpenCV didn't find your file. Try using the full path to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the image is not in your directory. Otherwise:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("thermal-imaging-opportunities.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output is:

[image]